# Apply the same content on all the frame of a beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, text

Is there a way to apply the same content (image or text) to every frame of a beamer ? 
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should give us more precise information, including which theme you are using for `beamer`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You could use a background template for that. (You need to compile this twice.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{tikz}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{repeat}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}[action]


\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[repeat]
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some title here}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Don't fry ducks}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Never}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]